# Ordering of broadcast control stream and main stream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

A bounded control stream is queue from Cassandra, and the main stream is read from Kafka.  My question is can we read and broadcast the control stream completely before process the main stream?

We are using Flink 1.9.3 and Java 8

Answer (score 0):

The standard technique for this is to somehow bootstrap the initial broadcast state into a savepoint. Then you can start the live job with its main stream from that savepoint.

For getting that state into a savepoint in the first place, there are two solutions:

1. Use the State Processor API. (I've never tried that with broadcast state, but I think it should work.) I have a [simple example](https://gist.github.com/alpinegizmo/ff3d2e748287853c88f21259830b29cf) that uses the State Processor API to bootstrap keyed state that might help you get started.
2. Run a modified version of the final job that is connected to the control stream, but that doesn't read from the primary stream. Take a savepoint once the control stream has been fully ingested. Then restart from the savepoint, with the primary stream enabled.

Better support for "side inputs" is planned, but is still future work.

UPDATE:

As of Flink 1.12, the State Processor API provides you with a savepoint connector that can be used with the DataSet API to read and write savepoints. So to implement solution #1 above, you would write a batch program using the DataSet API to create (or modify) a savepoint, and then use that savepoint to bootstrap the state of your DataStream program.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I read the State Processor API doc [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html#broadcast-state-1) once again, and I can give it  a try.

Since I'm new in Flink, in this scenario, it is normal to save a savepoint and read it again?  Is it a best practice?  Or I should use DataSet instead of DataStream?  Or it is no different?

Comment: Yes, using savepoints in this way is a normal practice. You'll have to use DataSet for reading and writing savepoints with the State Processor API, but you should otherwise avoid the DataSet API.

Comment: From my understanding, this API is using Flink's DataSet API, so read/write functions are using DataSet.  However, my main stream data are streamed from Kafka, can i connect the DataStream (main) to the DataSet (broadcast)?  I have to rewrite the application base on DataSet now?  eg. queue the main data from database into DataSet, instead of streaming data from Kafka?  Actually, in my application, I have other data are using DataStream API, not really want to change all to DataSet... :(

Comment: For the first approach, you would need to write two Flink jobs: one is a DataSet job that bootstraps a savepoint containing the state to be used by the other, which is your DataStream job.